Trying to identify where fees where deducted in seemingly domestic transfer
I use a gaming website (Sorare) that allows me to hold funds in USD. I decided to initiate a withdrawal and the fee shown on their site for the withdrawal was $0.25 and they use MangoPay as their payments provided. The $0.25 was shown as the fee when my account for withdrawals was a USA/USD bank account.
As I am a resident in Canada, I figured I would receive the funds at low cost in my Wise USD account, then exchange on Wise and withdraw in to a Canada/CAD account. If I used my Canada/CAD account on Sorare with a direct withdrawal, it was showing a fee of $8 which I figured was due to a wire fee which would also cost me more on the deposit side.
So I hit submit and the next day, I received an amount $20 short in to Wise. In addition, Wise deducted $4.14 from the received amount as their fee.
I have reached out to both parties to asked whether the amount sent was $20 less or the amount received was $20 less. Both sides are asking me to talk to the other.
Proof of transfer sent from Sorare/MangoPay:


Proof of transfer received by Wise:

I am just trying to understand which side I need to bug for more details now. This initially appeared to me to be a domestic ACH but I figure the only way someone took $20 along the way is it was a wire?

You should probably remove your account number from the screenshot

Based on the terms used, that “Proof of transfer sent” screenshot looks a lot more like a wire transfer than an ACH transaction.
